# Dropwizard Request Filters With URI Pattern

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I am building a RESTful application in Dropwizard. While connecting to a database, I want to set up a `UserNotFoundFilter` that implements `ContainerRequestFilter` so that incoming requests go through this filter first.

The idea is that I would like to have this specific filter only mapped to certain URI patterns. For instance, I want the filter to only apply to `/users/*` and not anything else. Is there a way to do this without resorting to custom annotations and implementation with `DynamicFeature` ?

```
@Provider
public class UserNotFoundFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        MultivaluedMap pathParams = uriInfo.getPathParameters(); // Should contain (uid: 1) pair for /users/1
        boolean userExists = // check against the database using above pathparam pair to see if user exists
        if (!userExists) 
            throw new WebApplicationException("User does not exist", Status.NOT_FOUND);
        // let the request through as user exists
    }
}
```

My UserResource class

```
public class UserResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/users/{uid}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User getUser(@PathParam("uid") String uid) {
        // Now I don't need to do the check here !
        // boolean userExists = check against database using uid path param
        // if (!userExists)
        //     throw new WebApplicationException("User does not exist", Status.NOT_FOUND);
        return database.getUser(uid);
    }
}
```

My ItemResource class

```
public class ItemResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/items/{uid}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Item getItem(@PathParam("uid") String uid) {
        return database.getItem(uid);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do

```
public class MyApplication extends Application<MyConfiguration> {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void run(MyConfiguration config, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        // ... do other things, register resources
        // this pseudocode, the UserNotFoundFilter only applies to URIs of the kind /users/*
        environment.jersey().register(new UserNotFoundFilter()).forUriPattern("/users/*");
```

I appreciate any example code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

For `Servlet` filter -

Probably what you are looking for is `addMappingForUrlPatterns` from `javax.servlet.FilterRegistration` interface to be used in your `run()` as -

```
 environment.servlets().addFilter("FilterName", UserNotFoundFilter.class)
          .addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet
                         .allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/users/*");
```

Signature of the above-used method is  -

```
public void addMappingForUrlPatterns(
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes, boolean isMatchAfter,
        String... urlPatterns);
```

---

***Edit*** - for binding dynamically :

Try and use `DynamicFeature` as

```
@Provider
public class UserNotFoundDynamicFilter implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext featureContext) {
       if (resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(UserRequired.class) != null) {
          featureContext.register(UserNotFoundFilter.class);
       }
    }
}
```

where you can define the `UserRequired` annotation as  -

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UserRequired {
}
```

and within your resources mark all `/users/*` apis with the same annotation as -

```
@GET
@Path("/users/{uid}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@UserRequired
public User getUser(@PathParam("uid") String uid) {
    // Now I don't need to do the check here !
    // boolean userExists = check against database using uid path param
    // if (!userExists)
    //     throw new WebApplicationException("User does not exist", Status.NOT_FOUND);
    return database.getUser(uid);
}
```

*Source*  - [jersey-filters](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/core.html#jersey-filters)

Comment: If I understand correctly, thatss a ServletFilter impl and not a ContainerRequestFilter implementation. I need a way to set a mapping for URL patterns on the latter.

Comment: @Kookz correct. Updated for `DynamicFeature` use of the same for the `ContainerRequestFilter` implementation.

Comment: In the case of the example above, you bound the filter to an annotation. Then I have to add the annotation to all resource methods under `/users`. Is there a way to specify that using a URL pattern, instead of the annotations ?

Comment: @Kookz - do you specify your resource methods, using a URL pattern? seems like you might want to process the resources using reflection in case you are interested to parse them in that case.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. If you're referencing the `@Path` annotation, then yes I do. My entire point with this question was if there was a way to use a `ContainerRequestFilter` and add a URL pattern mapping, so that I don't have to write annotations on every resource method I want to use it on.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a bunch of useful stuff in `((ContainerRequest) requestContext).getUriInfo()`, e.g. for matching `/users/*`

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

    String uriTemplate = ((ContainerRequest) requestContext).getUriInfo().getMatchedTemplates().stream().map(o -> o.getTemplate()).reduce("", (acc, template) -> template + acc);
    if (uriTemplate == "/users/{id}") {
        // matched!
    }

    String path = ((ContainerRequest) requestContext).getUriInfo().getPath();
    if (path.startsWith("users/")) {
        // matched!
    }
}
```

Get the actual user `id` in a similar way for your DB lookup.